# superclass access check failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.javac.KaptJavaCompiler (in unnamed module @0x603e2fc3) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.main to unnamed module @0x603e2fc3

I am facing this issue while compiling code with Iguana beta version.

Comment: upgrade org.jetbrains.kotlin.android version to 1.9.20